# Why my use of Intrinsics API is slower than naive solution?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I struggle to realize why my usage of intrinsics API is slower than just sum with foreach loop?

```
public class ArraySum
{
    private double[] data;

    public ArraySum()
    {
        if (!Avx.IsSupported)
        {
            throw new Exception("Avx is not supported");
        }

        var rnd = new Random();

        var list = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(rnd.Next(500));
        }

        data = list.ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Native()
    {
        int result = 0;
        foreach (int i in data)
        {
            result += i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Native: {result}");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public unsafe void Intrinsics()
    {
        int vectorSize = 256 / 8 / 4;
        var accVector = Vector256<double>.Zero;
        int i;
        var array = data;
        fixed (double* ptr = array)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= array.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize)
            {
                var v = Avx.LoadVector256(ptr + i);
                accVector = Avx.Add(accVector, v);
            }
        }
        double result = 0;
        var temp = stackalloc double[vectorSize];
        Avx.Store(temp, accVector);
        for (int j = 0; j < vectorSize; j++)
        {
            result += temp[j];
        }
        for (; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            result += array[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Intrinsics: {result}");
    }
```

Result:

> .NET SDK=6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57

```
|     Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median |
|----------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|     Native | 387.6 us | 12.15 us | 35.83 us | 405.8 us |
| Intrinsics | 393.2 us |  9.01 us | 25.70 us | 385.0 us |
```

what may be causing this?

It's running on Windows and Intel Core i5-3340M CPU 2.70GHz (Ivy Bridge) if it does matter

BenchmarkDotNet warns that ArraySum.Native: Default -> It seems that the distribution is bimodal (mValue = 3.92)

Comment: @bolov you're right, I just realized that Console is very slow :P thank you anyway

Comment: whatever it doesn't even count it correctly for some reason for bigger arrays

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that

native method should perform it on `double`s not `int`s, opsie

```
[Benchmark]
public void Native()
{
    double result = 0;
    foreach (double i in data)
    {
        result += i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Native: {result}");
}



|     Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median |
|----------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|     Native | 415.1 us | 25.35 us | 73.95 us | 385.9 us |
| Intrinsics | 388.7 us |  7.58 us | 21.74 us | 384.7 us |
```

but also:

`Console.WriteLine` adds probably too much overhead which is way higher than time spent performing sum and skews the results

now the difference is more significant:

```
[Benchmark]
public double Native()
{
    double result = 0;
    foreach (double i in data)
    {
        result += i;
    }

    return result;
}

[Benchmark]
public unsafe double Intrinsics()
{
    int vectorSize = 256 / 8 / 4;
    var accVector = Vector256<double>.Zero;
    int i;
    var array = data;
    fixed (double* ptr = array)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= array.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize)
        {
            var v = Avx.LoadVector256(ptr + i);
            accVector = Avx.Add(accVector, v);
        }
    }
    double result = 0;
    var temp = stackalloc double[vectorSize];
    Avx.Store(temp, accVector);
    for (int j = 0; j < vectorSize; j++)
    {
        result += temp[j];
    }
    for (; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        result += array[i];
    }

    return result;
}




|     Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|----------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
|     Native | 92.92 us | 1.547 us | 1.447 us |
| Intrinsics | 25.06 us | 0.459 us | 1.090 us |
```